# The integral is at most the length of the range of integration times the largest value of the integrand?

Tags: calculus, integration

(Source: MAT $2015$) Suppose we have two functions, $f(x)$ and $h(x)$. It is given that $h(x)-f(x)$ achieves a maximum value on the interval: $$0 \le x_0 \le \frac{1}{2}$$ at $x = x_0$. Explain why $$\int_{0}^{x}(h(t)-f(t))dt \le \frac{1}{2}(h(x_0)-f(x_0))$$ whenever $0\le x \le \frac{1}{2}$.

I looked up the solution for this question, and it said that "The integral is at most the length of the range of integration times the largest value of the integrand". i.e
$$\int_{0}^{x}(h(t)-f(t))dt \le x(h(x_0)-f(x_0))$$

It isn't obvious to me why this would be true. Can anyone please prove/explain this?

Comment: $h(t)-f(t) \le h(x_0)-f(x_0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a fact that if $f$ and $g$ are two integrable functions defined on $[a,b]$ such that $f(x) \le g(x)$ for all $x\in [a,b]$, then $$\int_a^b f(x)dx \le \int_a^b g(x)dx$$

In particular, if $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and attains some maximum $M$ on $[a,b]$, then $f(x) \le M$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, and then

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx \le \int_a^b Mdx = M \int_a^b 1 dx = M(b-a)$$

Now one way to see it geometrically is as follows. If $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$ and achieves there a maximum $M$, then we have three cases.

Case $1$: $M=0$. Then this is just obvious: the signed area of the region bounded by $f$ is $\le 0$ because $f$ never exceeds $M$ and so it's never positive. Hence,

$$\int_a^b f(x)dx \le 0 = M(b-a)$$

Case $2$: $M < 0$. Then, draw the line $y=M$. We know that $\int_a^b Mdx$ is just the signed area of the rectangle formed by the $x$-axis, the line $x=a$, the line $x=b$, and the line $y=M$. This (signed) area is just $M(b-a)$ (negative length times width). On the other hand, since $f$ is always below $M$, we know that the signed area under $f$ must be at most the area of the rectangle we just talked about, because if we disregard signs, the area under $f$ will be bigger than the area of the rectangle, and since signs are involved and both are negative, $M(b-a)$ will be $\ge$ the area under $f$.

Case $3$: $M>0$. The argument here is similar to case $2$.

Answer (score 1):

More generally, the claim is that, if $g(x) \le M$ on $[a,b]$, then
$$
\int_a^b g(x) \, \mathrm{d} x 
\le M(b-a)
$$
This can be viewed as a special case of the monotonicity of the integrand, in that if $g(x) \le h(x)$ on $[a,b]$ then
$$
\int_a^b g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
\le \int_a^b h(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$
Of course, if $h$ is a constant function (say, $M$), it is easy to integrate, and the result follows.